# making shallow angle in wood

Tags: powertools, routers, fascia

I'm thinking how to make a shallow angle - not too important what it is - in wood plank about 3'7" long (see cross section below).

I was thinking maybe a power planer might do but they're for making things flat. Some people on youtube put a bevel free hand but I do not think that would work.

Any ideas? There is the router but I think I'd probably need some fancy jig.

[image: cross section]

Comment: I note that the image is not to scale, you've exagerated the slope.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest thing would be to rip it on a table saw with the angle and depth set correctly.

Comment: I have a  table saw of the £30-50 variety but I do not think I'd get that to work with this its just too cheaply made.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a hand plane.

Another option is to tape a 2.5mm piece under the toe and run the whole thing though a thicknesser.

Comment: I do not have access to a thicknesser unless one can be improvised from a power plane.